# Ternary operator in bison, avoid both side computation

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, ternary-operator

I have this rule in my grammer for ternary operator:

```
 Int:
    Boolean  '?' Int ':' Int {if($1==1) $$=$3; else $$=$5;} 
  | ...
```

For numbers and expressions this works fine but suppose I have this code when `a` is integer:

```
a=5

1==1 ? a++ : a++
cout<<a;// now a==6 is the correct print but I got a==7
```

Both side of the ':' are computed but I need only one side. 
How can i do it in bison?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I see to accomplish what you want while keeping your one-pass interpreter approach would be to have a global flag that controls whether evaluation takes place (while that flag was set to `false`, the parsing rules would parse normally, but not execute anything, which you'd accomplish by enclosing each action in an `if`. The rule for the ternary operator could then invoke mid-rule actions or special parsing rules that set this flag according to the condition.

---

The proper way to solve this is by not executing the program directly in the parser. Instead let the parser build an AST (or some other intermediate representation if you prefer), which you then walk to execute the program in an additional stage.

In that stage you can then easily decide which branch to evaluate after evaluating the condition. The logic for that would look something like this:

```
class TernaryOperator : public IntExpression {
    // ...
  public:
    int eval() {
      if(condition.eval()) {
        return then_branch.eval();
      } else {
        return else_branch.eval();
      }
    }
}
```

Of course the above is only an example and might be better written using the visitor pattern instead.